# How to separate string characters and mathematical characters from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to separate the alphabetic string or number string and mathematical characters from a string.
For example -

```
var test = "test1+test2*3+(test3*6)";
I want to separate it like this - 

var result = ["test1", "+", "test2", "*", "3", "+", "(", "test3", "*", "6",")"];
```

Can anyone help me to get the result, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regular expression to either match a mathematical character, or any characters other than mathematical characters:

```js
var test = "test1+test2*3+(test3*6)";
var result = test.match(/[+*()]|[^+*()]+/g);
console.log(result);
// ->
// ["test1","+","test2","*","3","+","(","test3","*","6",")"]
```

- `[+*()]` - Match a single `+`, `*`, `(`, or `)` (feel free to add whichever characters you want to isolate here)
- `|` - OR
- `[^+*()]+` - Match anything *but* those characters, one or more times

Answer (score 2):

This gives the required matches:
/(\w+|\W)/gm

- \w+ matches any token/variable (like test1, test2 etc.)
- \W matches all operators

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = "test1+test2*3+(test3*6)";
var result = test.match(/\w+|\W/g);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = "test1+test2*3+(test3*6)";
var temp=''
var arr=[];
for(var i in test){

if((/[^A-Za-z0-9]/).test(test[i]))

{arr.push(temp)
arr.push(test[i])
temp='';

}
else{
temp+=test[i]
}
}
console.log(arr.filter((value)=>{return value!==''}))
```